# Flash doesn't appear in my Chromium "chrome://plugins" page

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-flash, plugins

I recently upgraded Chromium manually from http://build.chromium.org

I tried loading some Flash content and it won't load.

First I was thinking that maybe there's a problem with the plugin so I went to "`chrome://plugins`", it wasn't there, I tried installing, still wasn't there.

Went to `/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/42.0.2286.0/Chromium Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/`, there was no PepperFlash directory.

I copied from Google Chrome, reloaded Chromium, still nothing (No content and nothing appears in `chrome://plugins`).

Tried installing the Pepper Flash specifically from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ (Selecting My current Mac version and the PPAPI plugin from the other list below).

Still not working.

Any additional ideas? I'm really frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the system-flashplayer, but you have to enable "Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows" in about:flags first.

Comment: It seems that Chromium no longer supports NPAPI. No NPAPI in about:flags. Also I saw this info on one ubuntu forum.

Comment: I've found official blog http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Answer (score -1):

I set "Enable" to Enable Input IME API Windows, Linux in chrome://flags/ on my Win 64 Chromium and got the Flash Player in chrome://plugins/

Comment: I guess you wanted to comment to the thread above. :)